# How to Multiply True/False within list python

Tags: python

New in Python, I'm trying to do some tests. I've seen many examples but not a similar one yet.

Below are 2 'lists':

```
a = True
b = False
```

Questions: How can I create a new list based on x number of a and y number of b.

For eg:

```
list = [a * 4] + [b * 2] + [a * 3] 

output:

[True, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True]
```

Thanks for anyone helping!

Comment: Those aren't lists.

Comment: Yes thats why 'lists' because I want to create a list with those

Comment: Well, then do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close but you put everything inside brackets. Instead, to merge lists, you just had to use `[a]*4` etc. instead of `[a * 4]` etc. That's why you were getting `[4, 0, 3]` as the output.

```
output = [a] * 4 + [b] * 2 + [a] * 3 
# [True, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True]
```